# Show bitmap inside GridViewColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to display an icon inside a *GridViewColumn* having a bitmap (possibly I would like to set the size).
This is the class I'm using:

```
  class MyApp
  {
    private UInt64 Id;
    public string Process { get; set; }
    public string WindowTitle { get; set; }
    bool OnFocus;
    public System.Drawing.Bitmap Icon { get; set; }
  }
```

And this is how the XAML looks like:

```
<ListView x:Name="applicationList" Height="372" SelectionChanged="applicationList_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Process" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Process}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Window Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding WindowTitle}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Icon" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Icon}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I've already tried some solutions to other questions but nothing worked (I don't know much about WPF).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bitmap is Winform, use BitmapSource (or a derived type) instead. Then use an Image control in the CellTemplate of the GridViewColumn to show the bitmap.

Comment: @Clemens Can you be more specific? As I mentioned I'm not a WPF expert

Comment: Google "wpf gridviewcolum image". Get a WPF book?

Comment: @Clemens I changed Icon type to BitmapSource and the XAML including <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Icon}"/> inside a ColumnTemplate but nothing is displayed. – Alessandro Gaballo yesterday

Comment: @Clemens As I said, I'm not using a Bitmap  anymore, I changed it to System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource that I get using .Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(...)

Comment: Re-read my first comment: "Then use an Image control in the CellTemplate of the GridViewColumn to show the bitmap".

Comment: @Clemens I did it, take a look here http://pastebin.com/Qgx13kth